# Citing Web sources in line with APA7

Tags: biblatex, apa7

A scientific journal requests APA7 to be used for bibliography and referencing. It does not provide any style files or samples that help to meet this requirement. Using the user packages in the minimal example below, I managed to comply with their requirements except for the Web references. When I use the user packages in the minimal working example below, I get Web references in the following format:

> CIESIN - Center for International Earth Science Information Network, Columbia Uni696
> versity. (2018). Gridded population of the world, Version 4 (GPWv4): Population
> count, Revision 11. [Datasets]. Retrieved July 7, 2022, from https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v4-population-count-rev11
>
> NOAA - National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration. (n.d.). Version 4 DMSP-OLS
> nighttime lights time series, Stable Lights [Datasets]. Retrieved July 18, 2020, from
> https://ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/dmsp/downloadV4composites.html

However, the journal requests a slightly different wording of the Web references. I provide an example:

> Powertech Systems. (2015). Lithium-ion vs lead-acid cost analysis. Retrieved
> from http://www.powertechsystems.eu/home/tech-corner/lithium-ion-vs-lead-acid-cost-analysis/. Accessed January 6, 2016.

My question: Do you know what should be changed in order to meet journal's APA7 Web sources requirement? Thank you very much.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,eurosym,geometry,ulem,graphicx,caption,color,setspace,sectsty,comment,footmisc,caption,pdflscape,array, mathpazo, longtable,rotating, float, booktabs, lineno, subcaption, siunitx, caption, multirow, longtable,pdflscape,booktabs, csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in}
\begin{document}
```

Test

```
{\nocite{*} \normalsize 
    \doublespacing
    \printbibliography }
\end{document}
```

Sample bibliography entries:

```
@misc{sedac2018,
title     = {{Gridded population of the world, Version 4 (GPWv4): Population count, Revision 11. [Datasets]}},
author    = {{CIESIN - Center for International Earth Science Information
Network, Columbia University}},
publisher = {Palisades, New York: NASA Socioeconomic Data and Applications Center (SEDAC)},
year      =  2018,
url = {https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v4-population-count-rev11},
urldate  = {2022-07-07}
}

@misc{noaa,
title     = {{Version 4 DMSP-OLS nighttime lights time series, Stable Lights [Datasets]}},
author    = {{NOAA - National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration}},
url = {https://ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/dmsp/downloadV4composites.html},
urldate  = {2020-07-18}
}
```

Comment: Before you go down modifying `biblatex-apa` (which is generally not recommended and can be surprisingly difficult, because `biblatex-apa` sometimes has to work a lot to get APA style right), double-check with your journal that they actually accept `biblatex` submissions. `biblatex` requires a very different workflow than classical BibTeX (which is what most journals still want).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will ask the journal.